# Elevated permissions and Wix

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to copy files from windows temp files to "Program Files" directory using C# code as Custom Action in my installer, but I can't because of insufficient rights.
I tried to create deferred custom action but now `File.Exists` returns `false` for existing file. What I'm doing wrong?

Ideally I'd prefer to have 2 immediate custom actions...

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult Save(Session session) // immediate
    {
        try
        {

            string toBackup = = "C:\test.txt";
            string backup = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), Path.GetExtension(toBackup));
            File.Copy(toBackup, backup);
            session["BAK_PATH"] = backup;
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
    }

    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult Restore(Session session) // Deferred action
    {
        try
        {
            string INSTALLDIR = session["INSTALLDIR"];
            string target = Path.Combine(INSTALLDIR, "myfile.txt");
            string backup = session.CustomActionData["BakPath"]; // <- correct value
            File.Copy(backup, target); // backup doesn't exist
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't copy to program files with an immediate action. You will need to use deferred actions here. Put some log lines into your custom action so you can see where and what it is checking when looking for that file. Can you add your custom action code to the question as a code block?

Comment: I tried to use deferred actions. But they fail on `File.Exists`. There is no special logic: 1 action copies a file to temp folder, 2 action(deferred) tries to copy files from temp to program files...

Comment: You should look at the WiX CopyFile element instead of trying to code this.   http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html